# Remove total value for one column in PowerBI

Tags: r, sum, powerbi, dax

I have a table visualisation in PowerBI that sums the top 10 products sold by sales quantity. I have a calculated column which shows the rate of sale, using other fields from the data source:

`(quantity / # stores with product) / weeks on sale`

The ROS calculates correctly, but it still sums and appears in the total row.. The number of stores and number of weeks are set to 'Don't Summarize', but they still add together and give some meaningless number in the total row. If i set ROS to 'Don't Summarize', to remove the total row, the summing of the rest of the table and therefore the filter I have on top N by quantity drops out.

It is very frustrating! Is there an option somewhere to simply **not display total** for a field?? I don't want to remove the total row completely as the other fields (e.g. Qty, Value, Margin) are useful to see a sum of.. It seems very strange that it is so difficult to do something so minor..

Additional info:

**Qty** is a SUM field.

**Stores** is not summarized and simply refers to the average number of stores that stock that product over the weeks of the trading season
Weeks is not summarized.

**Weeks** is not summarized and refers to the weeks that have passed in the trading season.

Example data:

**Item.......Qty......Stores.....Weeks....ROS**

---

Itm1........600........390.........2............0.77

Itm2........444........461.........2............0.48

Itm3........348........440.........2............0.40

**Total.....1,392.....1,291*......6*...........1.65***

Fields marked with a * are those where the sum is a meaningless figure unrelated to the data. I do not actually need Stores and Weeks to show in the table, so the fact that they sum does not matter. However, ROS is essential, but the sum part is totally irrelevant and I do not want it to show. Any ideas? I am open to the idea of using R to overcome the lack of flexibility in the standard tables although my knowledge in this area is fairly limited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you've made a common mistake - using a Calculated Column for ROS where you should've used a Measure.

If you rebuild that calculation as a Measure, then you can wrap the **HASONEVALUE** function around it, with the objective of showing a blank when there are multiple Item values in context (the Total row).

Roughly the Measure formula would be:

```
ROS = IF ( HASONEVALUE ( Mytable[Item] ) , << calculation >> , BLANK() )
```

I would also replace your use of / with the DIVIDE function, to avoid divide by zero errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I did try though and the measure calculation wasn't giving the correct answer. Am I right in thinking that for a measure you can only use aggregations of columns (or other calculated columns/measures) in the formula? I wasn't able to find a formula using a measure that worked for me.

Comment: Yes.  For your formula it would be something like: DIVIDE ( DIVIDE ( SUM ( quantity ) , SUM ( # stores with product ) ) , SUM ( weeks on sale ) )

Comment: If you need row-level calcs, you can use the "X" functions e.g. SUMX.

Comment: I'm comin' in real late, but thank you for this. I initially found another "solution" on a blog that just didn't work for my scenario using ISFILTERED( Mytable[Item] ), but yours did.  Kudos to you, sir.

Answer (score 7):

You can remove individual totals for columns in tables and matrix objects in a round-about way by using field formatting.

Click the object, go to formatting, click the field formatting accordion, select the column or columns you want to affect from the drop-down list, set the font color to white, set 'apply to values' to off, and set 'apply to totals' to on.

A bit tedious if you have many columns, but you will have, in affect, whited-out the column totals.

Heads up, you might still have a problem with exporting data, though.

Cheers

Comment: Nice idea, but doesn't work if you are already styling the header a different colour. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the table -> Fields -> expand the value field you don't want to include -> Select "Don't Summarize." This will exclude it from the "Total" row.

Comment: This works only for columns. If you have a measure you do not have this option.

Answer (score -1):

select do not summarise option for those metrics which you dont want total

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, when you give an answer, try to explain a little bit how it works or why you answer is a good one.

Answer (score -1):

Select the table you want to change
In the Visualizations pane:
Go to Format,
Find the Field Formatting option,
Choose the field you don't want to summarize.
Turn off 'apply to header',
Turn off 'apply to values',
Turn ON 'apply to total',
Change the font color to white.